# Cannot convert MOV files to other video formats using avconv on Ubuntu

Tags: mov, video-conversion

I recently received some MOV files that had been recorded on an iPhone (not sure which version - I can get that info if needed).  I have been trying to convert these MOVs into another format (anything, really) so that I can edit the clips in kdenlive.  I have tried programs in Windows as well as vlc, ffmpeg and avconv in Ubuntu without success.  Attempting to convert the files to mp4 and avi using Realplayer on a Macintosh results in bad aspect ratios and degraded image quality.

I will post the results of trying to convert the file using avconv below.
The original MOV file I am trying to convert can be downloaded here:
http://www.unc.edu/~haksaeng/balloon/IMG_0347.MOV

Any guidance on how to successfully convert these files without losing (too much) quality would be greatly appreciated.  Ubuntu solutions are preferred but I will take anything at this point.

```
 avconv -i IMG_0347.MOV -f mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy output.mp4
 avconv version 0.8.6-4:0.8.6-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the Libav developers
  built on Apr  2 2013 17:00:59 with gcc 4.6.3
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x8c3e240] stream 0, error opening alias: path='/Users/',   dir='Roll 1', filename='IMG_0347.MOV', volume='Lees HD', nlvl_from=3, nlvl_to=3
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x8c3e240] stream 1, error opening alias: path='/Users/', dir='Roll 1', filename='IMG_0347.MOV', volume='Lees HD', nlvl_from=3, nlvl_to=3
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x8c3e240] Could not find codec parameters (Video: h264, 1920x1080, 18530 kb/s)
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'IMG_0347.MOV':
Metadata:
major_brand     : qt  
minor_version   : 537199360
compatible_brands: qt  
creation_time   : 2013-04-06 12:20:16
encoder         : 6.1.3
encoder-eng     : 6.1.3
date            : 2013-04-06T08:20:16-0400
date-eng        : 2013-04-06T08:20:16-0400
Duration: 00:00:05.15, bitrate: 9 kb/s
Stream #0.0(und): Video: h264, 1920x1080, 18530 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 600 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2013-04-06 12:20:16
Stream #0.1(und): Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 63 kb/s
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2013-04-06 12:20:16
File 'output.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
File 'output.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
major_brand     : qt  
minor_version   : 537199360
compatible_brands: qt  
creation_time   : 2013-04-06 12:20:16
date-eng        : 2013-04-06T08:20:16-0400
encoder-eng     : 6.1.3
date            : 2013-04-06T08:20:16-0400
encoder         : Lavf53.21.1
Stream #0.0(und): Video: libx264, 1920x1080, q=2-31, 18530 kb/s, 600 tbn, 600 tbc
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2013-04-06 12:20:16
Stream #0.1(und): Audio: libvo_aacenc, 44100 Hz, mono, 63 kb/s
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2013-04-06 12:20:16
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
 Press ctrl-c to stop encoding
frame=    0 fps=  0 q=-1.0 Lsize=       0kB time=10000000000.00 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s    
video:0kB audio:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead inf%
```

Now try playing it with mplayer:

```
mplayer output.mp4 
MPlayer svn r34540 (Ubuntu), built with gcc-4.6 (C) 2000-2012 MPlayer Team
mplayer: could not connect to socket
mplayer: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.

Playing output.mp4.
libavformat version 53.21.1 (external)
Mismatching header version 53.19.0
libavformat file format detected.
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x1e013a0]Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
LAVF: no audio or video headers found - broken file?
Quicktime/MOV file format detected.
No stream found.


Exiting... (End of file)
```

Answer (score 0):

mov files sometimes contain aliases, that are references to other files. ffmpeg and libav can load them for you if they stored as a relative path (and if files are actually present there).
Newer version of ffmpeg can load sources from absolute paths (such as in your case) if you add `-use_absolute_path 1` to your command line.